# URL Wont Redirect to HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

I have added a the below rewrite IIS rule to my web.config. But my website won't redirect to https. Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

If I navigate to http://www.example.com it wont redirect to https and would return 200 OK.

But, if I navigate to http://example.com it redirects to https://example.com (301 -> 200)

```html
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^(.*)$" />
 <conditions>
  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules See what FRT says.

Comment: According to your rule, I have created a test demo, it seems it works well. I guess the www.example.com domain map another web applicatio not example.com domain mapped web application. I suggest you could try to see its DNS setting to make sure it redirect to the same application.